# Simulating realistic noise for a calcium baseline

Tags: r, simulation, noise

thanks to the truely amazing community my project group is one step closer to mimic realistic calcium baseline noise.

I simulated a typical calcium movement in a mathematical model:
[image]

Thanks to the community I could add random noise to the unrealistic baseline:

[image]

However, the noise dynamic is actually too fast. Is there a way to slow down the noise and create broader noise peaks instead of these spikes. I add an actual measurement to show you what I mean:

[image]

If this question is too specific, I apologize and will delete the post.

Best wishes and many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make your question and examples [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2572423) so that others can help. That being said, it looks like the baseline is a just a random normal -- probably created with something like `x <- rnorm(500)`. One way to make this less jumpy is calculate a moving average. You could use a package like `TTR` or `zoo` to do this, or you can create your own function. For example:

```
x <- rnorm(500)
plot(x, type = "l")
```

[image]

```
ma <- function(x, n = 5){ filter(x, rep(1/n, n), sides = 2) }
plot(ma(x), type = "l")
```

[image]

```
plot(ma(x, 10), type = "l")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Jason - the result looks good; however, for my purpose I would have to choose a quite high n-value (ca. 1500) for an x of size 159,957. The higher I go with n, the larger there is a NA-area in the data. First I thought n should simply be a multiple of x but still there is quite a stretch of unidentified Y-values when plotting the data. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: alright simply clipped of the NA-part - thanks to all :)

Answer (score 1):

I see your point now. I have two suggestions for this case, maybe they will be of help :

Try to add noise to only a subset of your base line ( following is a 10%)

```
baseline.index = which(App[,2] == min(App[,2]))
baseline.index.subset = sample(x = baseline.index, size = 0.1 * length ( baseline.index) , replace = F)
noise = rnorm( length (baseline.index.subset))
App[ baseline.index.subset,2] = App[ baseline.index.subset,2] + noise
```

And try to  play a bit with the mean and standard deviation of the noise. ie:

```
noise = rnorm( length (baseline.index.subset), mean = 0, sd = 0.1)
```

Let us know if this helps